# Which DB2 client package is needed to compile embedded SQL programs?

Tags: linux, db2

I have to work on some embedded SQL files (`.sqc`) for DB2 which will be compiled on Linux. The DB2 command line processor (`db2` command) has to be used for precompilation.

What of the many DB2 client installation packages contains this program and other dependencies that are needed for embedded SQL program compilation?

Comment: What is the context? What version of DB2? Do you mean by "package" which type of driver to download? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24040536

Comment: The product uses Embedded SQL (.sqc) files which after precompilation generates .c source files. These generated source file can be compile with gcc. The created binary apps will be connecting to DB2 server.                  Now to convert these embedded sqlc file to c, db2 command is used. Which package is db2 command line utility located in? It might be some client package, there are some 2 to 3 client packages available for db2. I am confused as to which package to be installed to get db2 precompiler.

Comment: I understand the part about how DB2 works :). It seems that by "package" you mean a software package to be downloaded from the IBM website, not something you install via yum or apt-get etc.

Comment: Excatly Henrik, I want to know which package needs to be downloaded from IBM's site.

Comment: How's this off-topic? you folks who voted to close -- you should refrain from that if you have no idea about the content of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description you need the so-called IBM Data Server Client Package. It includes development tools and all you need to process `.sqc` files. For a [list of available (other) packages see here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html).

The key is that you need the precompiler to process the `.sqc` files and the header and library files to later on compile them with gcc.

Comment: Hi Henrick,Thanks for the info. Is this package free software or licensed >

Comment: It is licensed software, but there are no costs.

Comment: Do you mean to say that its free to use but usage is restricted to license terms ?

Comment: Yes, most open source SW also has a license and you are bound to that. Here, it is an IBM SW license and proprietary SW, but free to use with DB2.

Answer (score 0):

While the DB2 command line processor (the "db2" you mention) is available in both IBM Data Server Runtime Client and IBM Data Server Client, only the latter contains the C header files necessary for compilation.

Download from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053).

Comment: Is this freeware or licensed one